# calculating average of values in column of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, file, csv

Ok, so I recently asked about how to get access to individual columns of an array in java, and I got an answer that worked perfectly. I then however intended to calculate things such as the maximum value in this column, and the average. However, I came across an issue. In order to access each value, I assume this column needs to be treated as an array also. However, the way I got access to each column was by storing it into a double. Therefore, I have no idea how to take each column and calculate things. Can anyone help me please? I'm sorry for posting so much that probably seems like nothing here, but we had no teacher for 12 weeks and are expected to turn in this work by just teaching ourselves, and I'm just really stuck.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;//Importing any required tools.
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class CSVFiles extends JFrame { //Class, inherits properties of the JFrame. 

    private JPanel contentPane; //Create a container for the GUI.
    //Create other components used in the GUI
    private JTextField maxTxtVCC;
    private JTextField maxTxtTemp;
    private JTextField maxTxtLight;
    private JTextField minTxtLight;
    private JTextField avTxtLight;
    private JTextField minTxtTemp;
    private JTextField avTxtTemp;
    private JTextField minTxtVCC;
    private JTextField avTxtVCC;
    private JButton btnMax;
    private JButton btnMin;
    private JButton btnAv;
    private JTextField opnTxt;
    private JButton btnOpn;
    private TextArea textArea;
    private JFileChooser fc; 

    private String content = "";
    String [] contentCSV = new String [53000]; //String array to hold the data, 2000 gives more than enough space
    int totalValues; //Used to hold the amount of values in the array (52790 ish)
    Double[][] values;
    double c4, c5, c6;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) { //Main method
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { //Create a runnable method
                try {
                    CSVFiles frame = new CSVFiles(); //Launch the GUI
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); //Print errors
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public CSVFiles() { //Open constructor

        super ("CSV Files"); //Create a title for the GUI

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Instruct how the GUI is closed
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600); //Set size and location
        contentPane = new JPanel(); //Declare the JPanel
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)); //Create a boarder
        setContentPane(contentPane); //Add the JPanel
        contentPane.setLayout(null); //Set the layout

        maxTxtVCC = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        maxTxtVCC.setBounds(113, 534, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        maxTxtVCC.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(maxTxtVCC); //Add to the content pane

        maxTxtTemp = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        maxTxtTemp.setBounds(113, 503, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        maxTxtTemp.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(maxTxtTemp); //Add to the content pane

        maxTxtLight = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        maxTxtLight.setBounds(113, 472, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        maxTxtLight.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(maxTxtLight); //Add to the content pane

        JLabel lblLight = new JLabel("Light"); //Declare this label
        lblLight.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14)); //Set the font and size of text
        lblLight.setBounds(22, 469, 46, 17); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(lblLight); //Add to the content pane

        JLabel lblTemp = new JLabel("Temperature"); //Declare this label
        lblTemp.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14)); //Set the font and size of text
        lblTemp.setBounds(10, 503, 109, 17); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(lblTemp);

        JLabel lblVCC = new JLabel("VCC"); //Declare this label
        lblVCC.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14)); //Set the font and size of text
        lblVCC.setBounds(22, 534, 46, 17); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(lblVCC); //Add to the content pane

        minTxtLight = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        minTxtLight.setBounds(221, 472, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        minTxtLight.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(minTxtLight); //Add to the content pane

        avTxtLight = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        avTxtLight.setBounds(331, 472, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        avTxtLight.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(avTxtLight); //Add to the content pane

        minTxtTemp = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        minTxtTemp.setBounds(221, 503, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        minTxtTemp.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(minTxtTemp); //Add to the content pane

        avTxtTemp = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        avTxtTemp.setBounds(331, 503, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        avTxtTemp.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(avTxtTemp); //Add to the content pane

        minTxtVCC = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        minTxtVCC.setBounds(221, 534, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        minTxtVCC.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(minTxtVCC); //Add to the content pane

        avTxtVCC = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        avTxtVCC.setBounds(331, 534, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        avTxtVCC.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(avTxtVCC); //Add to the content pane

        btnMax = new JButton("Maximum"); //Declare this button
        btnMax.setBounds(110, 438, 89, 23); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(btnMax); //Add to the content pane

        btnMin = new JButton("Minimum"); //Declare this button
        btnMin.setBounds(221, 438, 89, 23); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(btnMin); //Add to the content pane

        btnAv = new JButton("Average"); //Declare this button
        btnAv.setBounds(328, 438, 89, 23); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(btnAv); //Add to the content pane

        textArea = new TextArea(); //Declare this text area
        textArea.setBounds(22, 55, 551, 367); //Set size and location
        textArea.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(textArea); //Add to the content pane

        btnOpn = new JButton("Open File"); //Declare this button
        btnOpn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Add an action listener to this button
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { //Method for action performed
                try{
                    fc = new JFileChooser(); //Declare the file chooser
                    fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV Files", "csv")); //Add a filter for only choosing CSV files
                    fc.removeChoosableFileFilter(fc.getAcceptAllFileFilter()); //Remove option to select any file type

                    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(contentPane); // Open the file chooser
                    File f; //Create a file to hold the data

                    //If the selected file is approved by the file chooser...
                    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                        f = fc.getSelectedFile(); //Stored selected file into file variable

                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = "";

                        textArea.append("Opening "+ f.getAbsolutePath()); //Print out file path
                        textArea.append("\nLoading file...\n\n");  //Print out loading message and some new lines

                        in.readLine(); //Skip the first line as it's just headers
                        int index = 0; //Integer used to label the indexes of the array


                            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                                builder.append(line);
                                builder.append("\n");
                                index++; //increment the index to move the next one up for the next line

                                String temp[] = line.split(",");
                                c4 = Double.parseDouble(temp[3]);
                                c5 = Double.parseDouble(temp[4]);
                                c6 = Double.parseDouble(temp[5]);
                            }

                        totalValues = index; //Set a value to the total values
                        textArea.append(builder.toString()); //Using the string builder to compile the text
                        textArea.append("\n*** End of File"); //Print the file onto the text area and an end of file message
                        in.close(); //Close the reader.

                        values = new Double [index][3];

                    }
                    else{
                        f = null;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnOpn.setBounds(484, 26, 89, 23); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(btnOpn); //Add to the content pane

        opnTxt = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        opnTxt.setBounds(22, 27, 452, 20); //Set size and location
        opnTxt.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(opnTxt); //Add to the content pane
    }

    //Methods for Calculations
    public static double findMax(double[] array){
        double max;
        max = array[0];

        for(int i=1;i<array.length;++i){
            if(array[i]>max){
                max = array[i];
            }   
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

Also, after this, I tried an alterantive code, where instead of getting individual columns, I would instead store the unwanted columns into an array so they are voided during calculation, but this also does not work. I'll admit very much that I didn't fully understand this method, but it was based on an example code that was given to us without any explanation of what it was doing, so I thought I'd atleast try. It displays the file on the text area, but gives a null pointer exception when I tried to click the max button. http://gyazo.com/27ef7cf9f4bc0c72ecdc3c1f84e6d0f8 Again, appriciate any help. I'm trying to rush a bit cuz my class is coming to me for help cuz last year, I watched a series on java basics in my free time and so had no trouble with our first year work, and they came to me for help. However, I have found no java series or anything on stuff like this, just like specific videos that only help a little. So yeah, really big thanks for any help. :)

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;//Importing any required tools.
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class CSVFiles extends JFrame { //Class, inherits properties of the JFrame. 

    private JPanel contentPane; //Create a container for the GUI.
    //Create other components used in the GUI
    private JTextField maxTxtVCC;
    private JTextField maxTxtTemp;
    private JTextField maxTxtLight;
    private JTextField minTxtLight;
    private JTextField avTxtLight;
    private JTextField minTxtTemp;
    private JTextField avTxtTemp;
    private JTextField minTxtVCC;
    private JTextField avTxtVCC;
    private JButton btnMax;
    private JButton btnMin;
    private JButton btnAv;
    private JTextField opnTxt;
    private JButton btnOpn;
    private TextArea textArea;
    private JFileChooser fc; 

    private String content = "";
    String [] contentCSV = new String [53000]; //String array to hold the data, 2000 gives more than enough space
    int totalValues; //Used to hold the amount of values in the array (52790 ish)
    Double[][] values;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) { //Main method
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { //Create a runnable method
                try {
                    CSVFiles frame = new CSVFiles(); //Launch the GUI
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); //Print errors
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public CSVFiles() { //Open constructor

        super ("CSV Files"); //Create a title for the GUI

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Instruct how the GUI is closed
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600); //Set size and location
        contentPane = new JPanel(); //Declare the JPanel
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)); //Create a boarder
        setContentPane(contentPane); //Add the JPanel
        contentPane.setLayout(null); //Set the layout

        maxTxtVCC = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        maxTxtVCC.setBounds(113, 534, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        maxTxtVCC.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(maxTxtVCC); //Add to the content pane

        maxTxtTemp = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        maxTxtTemp.setBounds(113, 503, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        maxTxtTemp.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(maxTxtTemp); //Add to the content pane

        maxTxtLight = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        maxTxtLight.setBounds(113, 472, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        maxTxtLight.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(maxTxtLight); //Add to the content pane

        JLabel lblLight = new JLabel("Light"); //Declare this label
        lblLight.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14)); //Set the font and size of text
        lblLight.setBounds(22, 469, 46, 17); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(lblLight); //Add to the content pane

        JLabel lblTemp = new JLabel("Temperature"); //Declare this label
        lblTemp.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14)); //Set the font and size of text
        lblTemp.setBounds(10, 503, 109, 17); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(lblTemp);

        JLabel lblVCC = new JLabel("VCC"); //Declare this label
        lblVCC.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14)); //Set the font and size of text
        lblVCC.setBounds(22, 534, 46, 17); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(lblVCC); //Add to the content pane

        minTxtLight = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        minTxtLight.setBounds(221, 472, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        minTxtLight.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(minTxtLight); //Add to the content pane

        avTxtLight = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        avTxtLight.setBounds(331, 472, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        avTxtLight.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(avTxtLight); //Add to the content pane

        minTxtTemp = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        minTxtTemp.setBounds(221, 503, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        minTxtTemp.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(minTxtTemp); //Add to the content pane

        avTxtTemp = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        avTxtTemp.setBounds(331, 503, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        avTxtTemp.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(avTxtTemp); //Add to the content pane

        minTxtVCC = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        minTxtVCC.setBounds(221, 534, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        minTxtVCC.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(minTxtVCC); //Add to the content pane

        avTxtVCC = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        avTxtVCC.setBounds(331, 534, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        avTxtVCC.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(avTxtVCC); //Add to the content pane

        btnMax = new JButton("Maximum"); //Declare this button
        btnMax.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                double tempArray1 [] = new double [totalValues];
                double tempArray2 [] = new double [totalValues];
                double tempArray3 [] = new double [totalValues];

                for (int i = 0; i < totalValues; i++){
                    tempArray1[i] = values[i][0]; //assign the indexes along side each individual sensor from sensor value
                    tempArray2[i] = values[i][1];
                    tempArray3[i] = values[i][2];
                }

                //execute the method defined in Utils.java to calculate maximum
                maxTxtLight.setText(findMax(tempArray1)+"");
                maxTxtTemp.setText(findMax(tempArray2)+"");
                maxTxtVCC.setText(findMax(tempArray3)+"");
            }
        });
        btnMax.setBounds(110, 438, 89, 23); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(btnMax); //Add to the content pane

        btnMin = new JButton("Minimum"); //Declare this button
        btnMin.setBounds(221, 438, 89, 23); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(btnMin); //Add to the content pane

        btnAv = new JButton("Average"); //Declare this button
        btnAv.setBounds(328, 438, 89, 23); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(btnAv); //Add to the content pane

        textArea = new TextArea(); //Declare this text area
        textArea.setBounds(22, 55, 551, 367); //Set size and location
        textArea.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(textArea); //Add to the content pane

        btnOpn = new JButton("Open File"); //Declare this button
        btnOpn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Add an action listener to this button
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { //Method for action performed
                try{
                    fc = new JFileChooser(); //Declare the file chooser
                    fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV Files", "csv")); //Add a filter for only choosing CSV files
                    fc.removeChoosableFileFilter(fc.getAcceptAllFileFilter()); //Remove option to select any file type

                    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(contentPane); // Open the file chooser
                    File f; //Create a file to hold the data

                    //If the selected file is approved by the file chooser...
                    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                        f = fc.getSelectedFile(); //Stored selected file into file variable

                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = "";

                        textArea.append("Opening "+ f.getAbsolutePath()); //Print out file path
                        textArea.append("\nLoading file...\n\n");  //Print out loading message and some new lines

                        in.readLine(); //Skip the first line as it's just headers
                        int index = 0; //Integer used to label the indexes of the array


                            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                                builder.append(line);
                                builder.append("\n");
                                index++; //increment the index to move the next one up for the next line
                            }


                        totalValues = index; //Set a value to the total values
                        textArea.append(builder.toString()); //Using the string builder to compile the text
                        textArea.append("\n*** End of File"); //Print the file onto the text area and an end of file message
                        in.close(); //Close the reader.

                        values = new Double [index][3];

                        for(int i = 0; i < totalValues; i++){
                            String cols[] = contentCSV[i].split(",");

                            String tempMillis = cols[0]; //Use a string to take the millis stamp out of the array
                            String tempStamp = cols[1]; //Use a string to take the time stamp out of the array
                            String tempDateTime = cols[2]; //Use a string to take the date stamp out of the array

                            for(int columns=3;columns<cols.length;++columns){
                                //temp sensor value holds the 9 sensors and the index numbers, parsing the data into double
                                values[i][columns-3] = Double.parseDouble(cols[columns]);
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        f = null;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnOpn.setBounds(484, 26, 89, 23); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(btnOpn); //Add to the content pane

        opnTxt = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        opnTxt.setBounds(22, 27, 452, 20); //Set size and location
        opnTxt.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(opnTxt); //Add to the content pane
    }

    //Methods for Calculations
    public static double findMax(double[] array){
        double max;
        max = array[0];

        for(int i=1;i<array.length;++i){
            if(array[i]>max){
                max = array[i];
            }   
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: To get better answers please read: http://sscce.org/ There is much irrelevant code here..

Comment: You don't tell us what you have tried. I feel that your going from one question to the next without understanding of java fundamentals.

Comment: Well, I used the answer to parse data from the String array into double values that then hold the individual columns, but when I then tried to split the individual columns into an array, it can;t cuz the slit method is for string values. So I don't know how to take the column say c4, which is a double value of the numbers in the column in the array, and then treat each value in that individually for calculations.

Comment: If you scroll the code just right the block patterns make a wave. Or buildings if you turn your head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                                builder.append(line);
                                builder.append("\n");
                                index++; //increment the index to move the next one up for the next line

                                String temp[] = line.split(",");
                                c4 = Double.parseDouble(temp[3]);
                                c5 = Double.parseDouble(temp[4]);
                                c6 = Double.parseDouble(temp[5]);
                            }
```

Your storing your values into **temporary local** (local to the while loop) variables.
These variables are re-assigned every loop so you lose the information.

You can do one of two things:

1. Calculate the running SUM, and number of rows in order to calculate the average at the end. Average = SUM / COUNT
2. Store all values in arraylists, and calculate average at the end.

**Example:**

```
double c4avg=0, c5avg=0, c6avg=0;

 while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                                builder.append(line);
                                builder.append("\n");
                                index++; //increment the index to move the next one up for the next line

                                String temp[] = line.split(",");
//Calculate Running Sum stored in AVG variable
                                    c4avg += Double.parseDouble(temp[3]);
                                    c5avg += Double.parseDouble(temp[4]);
                                    c6avg += Double.parseDouble(temp[5]);
                                }
//Divide by total rows to get average
    c4avg/=index;
    c5avg/=index;
    c6avg/=index;
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I've been stuck on this code for so long I never even clicked that these are created in the loop. I feel even more stupid than I am x) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: So, the += operator is like adding every value from that column into the variable c4avg, but how would I add the values individually into an array or list? I tried writing like
double[] c4vals += Double.parseDouble(temp[3]);
but that does not work x)